# How do I get multiple rows returned to java from a postgresql function,,, NOT mySQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, function, stored-procedures

I am trying to get 3 fields from 1 table using a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_search_test_ui_test_prog_revision(dev TEXT)
RETURNS table (dev_op_test_id BIGINT, test_program_name TEXT, test_program_revision TEXT) 
AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
    SELECT dev_op_test_id, test_program_name, test_program_revision
    FROM dev_op_test
    WHERE device = dev
    ORDER BY dev_op_test_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The JAVA code is below: (device is a String passed to this method)

```
    // Get unique devices from dev_op_test
    String sql = " SELECT sp_search_test_ui_test_prog_revision(" + device + ") ";
    PreparedStatement statement = pgConn.prepareStatement(sql);

    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

    // Clear from previous run
    cboTestProgDev.getItems().clear();

    while (rs.next()) {
        TestProgRev tpr = new TestProgRev();
        tpr.setDevOpTestId(rs.getLong(1));
        tpr.setTestProgramName(rs.getString(2));
        tpr.setTestProgramRevision(rs.getString(3));
        testProgs.add(tpr);
        cboTestProgDev.getItems().add(tpr.toString());
    }
```

And this is the error I keep getting. Notice it's telling me the column doesn't exist, which is true because that is a value not a column name. Any ideas???
[image]

Comment: Also see https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/callproc.html

Comment: THanks for pointing me to a solution that does NOT work with postgresql AS stated in the question title!!!

Comment: Er, but what about the link I gave you directly above in the comments?  Also I suggest that if you want help, lose the attitude.